# Is it pythonic to write decorators that doesn't return a callable?

Tags: python, django, functional-programming, decorator

I observed that python decorator need not return a callable.  Tried below example in a django queryset.  Is it some how a bad practice?

```
class MyQuerySet(models.QuerySet):

    ...

    def each(self, save=False, func=None):
        if hasattr(save, '__call__'):
            func = save
            save = False
        for obj in self:
            func(obj)
            if save:
                obj.save()

MyModel.objects.each(lambda x: x.delete())  # Delete all the mymodels from database

@Person.objects.each(save=True):
def make_older(person):
    ''' Increase age of all people '''
    person.age += 1
```

PS:

Are there any situations where this technique can be used for more useful purpose?

Comment: Can you post some valid code: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: Decorators are only syntactic sugar, so the question is, why would you want to use decorator syntax for that?  Does it make the code simpler or easier to maintain?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Python Glossary](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html):

> **decorator**
>
> A function returning another function, usually applied as a function transformation using the @wrapper syntax. Common examples for decorators are classmethod() and staticmethod().

**Edit:** A decorator that does not return a callable would not fall under this official defnition of the term 'decorator'. It would by unpythonic.

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question?